# How do key/value stores manage concurrency?

Tags: concurrency, key-value, atomic, key-value-store

I have read a number of articles stating key value stores only require two operations:

- `set(key, value)`
- `get(key)`

This is fine for a single process, but when you have multiple processes, how does the key value store manage concurrency? I would have thought a version number (E.g., an unsigned integer) used for ***compare-and-swap*** style concurrency would be required. E.g., the two operations would be:

- `set(key, value, version)`, where `version` is the ***condition*** - a mismatch causes a concurrency error and a successful match causes an increment.
- `get(key)` (returning both the `value` and the `version`).

Comment: Most key/value structures are not thread-safe on all operations. It's up to the user to avoid data race.

Comment: Avoid data races by using mutexes, etc? This wouldn’t be possible from separate machines with a shared KV store.

Comment: For shared KV stores, they work like databases, and usually have different levels race-handling mechanism. You have to check their specific documents. Your version number solution maybe one of them, but the real implementation is more complicated.

Comment: Could you point me to any articles with more information?

Comment: @user1420752 did you look at my answer, is there something I can do to improve it?

Comment: @amirouche After a lot of reading, I've found a significant number of approaches. In addition to MVCC and locking, there are vector clocks, timestamps, etc, and all sorts of combinations of single-master and multi-master (repair-on-read) scenarios. Repair-on-read is dangerous for critical (e.g., financial) data due to application "reconcilliation of" (or "selection between") multiple versions, which allows the discarding of *committed* data. ROR is great for sessions, shopping carts, etc, but definitely not for single-source-of-truth data.

Comment: @magnus make an answer to your own question please :)

Answer (score 3):

There is two kind of design. Some are using locks and other are using [MultiVersion Concurrency Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control).

MVCC achieve concurrency without locks. It can be summed up as:

- In a single read, the database return the latest version of the data
- In a single write, the databae add a new version for the data
- In the case of read/write concurrent request, the read get the most recent version of the data, that is before the current write.
- In the case of write/write concurrent request, **I think** that one of the write is abandonned and replayed later.